# Error 502 Bad Gateway With Some SMS Redirect Requests

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I have a link to a server to redirect the SMS to. It doesn't always work. I currently tried it with two numbers so far. I am using it for password reset if a user forgets their password. We have the following cases:
1. If the body is 1, send the password to the sender.
2. If the body is a number(+xxx or 00xxx) make it in the correct format and send the message to the number in the body
3. If the number is local, add the international sign and send the message to the number in the body.

I have my number and my colleague's number. We both tried sending 1 and it worked. He sent my number and it didn't work. I sent my number and his number and both worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Try re-wording it.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, I can't be sure. If it works with one input but not another, it's probably not a server configuration issue (as it would only return errors for all input). Adding error exception logging would be a good first step, if you don't already have it.